# How to convert text only in brackets to uppercase in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, uppercase, lowercase, brackets

So I'm looking for a way to convert text like this
`[sample]` into `[SAMPLE]` for example.

I already found a way to find text inside brackets like this one
`\[([a-z][\S\s]+?)\]` but I'm looking for a way to `replace with` that actually turns the text inside uppercase with the brackets preserved.

Answer (score 1):

In the `Replace with` field type:

```
[\U\1]
```

The `\U` modifier converts the following match into uppercase. You need to type the brackets too to preserve them.